# on_message and on_private_message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, c9.io, xmpp4r

I am currently using XMPP4R on [Cloud9](https://c9.io).

```
conference.on_message {|time, nick, text|
     case text
        when /regex/i
            #Same Command as on_private_message
        end
     end
}

conference.on_private_message {|time,nick, text|
     case text
        when /regex/i
            #Same Command as on_message
        end
     end
}
```

`conference.on_message` is the conference's message from a chat, and `conference.on_private_message` is the conference's private message chat.

I want to make both on_message and on_private_message to function as 1 instead of 2 shown above.

I tried something like this (below), but it worked only `conference.on_private_message`. How can I make it possible?

```
(conference.on_message || conference.on_private_message) { |time, nick, text|
    case text
        when /regex/i
            #Same Command on both on_message and on_private_message
        end
     end  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the purpose is to DRY your code. It might be worth creating a Proc object and sending it to both functions.

```
proc = Proc.new { |time, nick, text|
case text
    when /regex/i
        #Same Command on both on_message and on_private_message
    end
 end  
}
conference.on_message(&proc)
conference.on_private_message(&proc)
```

You could also try using #send method.

```
[:on_message, :on_private_message].each { |m| conference.send(m, &proc) }
```